# Process won't exit as soon as it is finished executing when used with waitFor(timeout, unit) method

Tags: java, java-8

I want to execute some cmd commands using java so i am using ProcessBuilder. Below is my sample code. I am running this code on Windows 10 pro build 19042 and using oracle java jdk1.8.0_191

```
public class ProcessBuilderEx {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String[] command = new String[]{"python", "-c", "\"help('modules')\""};
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
    processBuilder.command(command);

    Process process = processBuilder.start();
    InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
    process.waitFor(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    Stream<String> lines = bufferedReader.lines();
    lines.forEach(System.out::println);

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println((end - start) / 1000);
  }

}
```

When there is no waitFor() method is used, process exits as soon as it gets result and program is terminated. However, when waitFor(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) method is used process wont exit when it gets result but wait for given timeout and gets result then exit.

Below is documentation of method

```
Causes the current thread to wait, if necessary, until the subprocess represented by this Process object has terminated, or the specified waiting time elapses.
If the subprocess has already terminated then this method returns immediately with the value true. If the process has not terminated and the timeout value is less than, or equal to, zero, then this method returns immediately with the value false.
The default implementation of this methods polls the exitValue to check if the process has terminated. Concrete implementations of this class are strongly encouraged to override this method with a more efficient implementation.
Params:
timeout – the maximum time to wait
unit – the time unit of the timeout argument
Returns:
true if the subprocess has exited and false if the waiting time elapsed before the subprocess has exited.
Throws:
InterruptedException – if the current thread is interrupted while waiting.
NullPointerException – if unit is null
Since:
1.8
public boolean waitFor(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
        throws InterruptedException...
```

As per mentioned in documentation for method #waitFor(long timeout, TimeUnit unit), it should return result as soon as it gets it but it is waiting for entire 20 seconds time out and then terminated. I don't understand this behavior. Is it bug or am i missing something.

Comment: The pipe has a limited capacity. Since you’re not reading the `inputStream` while being blocked in `waitFor`, you have a deadlock. If all you’re going to do with the output, is to write it to your own standard output, you should not use a pipe at all but call [`inheritIO()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO--) on the `ProcessBuilder` before starting the child process. Then, the child process will write to your process’ standard output and you don’t have to deal with it at all.

Comment: As Holger said, using inheritIO() is the best approach.  In general, though, since `waitFor` waits for the process to end, you should call `waitFor` *after* reading the output of a process.  It doesn’t make sense to read output from a process that has finished and is no longer generating output.

Comment: Solution that you mentioned worked and satisfied my need. Thank you.